# Rendering template variables?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

The template is rendering this:

```
Hello, [<Student: Bob Frediricko>]. How are you?
```

But I want it to render:

```
Hello, Bob. How are you?
```

The view does this:

```
q = Student.objects.filter(pk=1)

for f in survey_formset:
    f.helper.layout = Layout(HTML("""
                    Hello, {{ q }}. How are you?
                    """))
```

the student model has...

```
def __unicode__ (self):
    return smart_unicode(self.first_name+" "+self.last_name)
```

Thanks for the help :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` returns a list, which is what you are seeing stringified in your rendered template.

Try this instead:

```
q = Student.objects.filter(pk=1)[0]
```

Or better yet, since you are selecting by pk (which is unique):

```
q = Student.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was something simple. Thank you.